# Upgraded Xcode - IQKeyboardManager Cocoapod not working

Tags: swift, cocoapods, iqkeyboardmanager

I recently upgraded my Xcode. I was able to transform all my code to Swift 3 but my CocoaPods was not. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look like the pod you are talking about has a Swift 3 version, so it should be no problem. Have you tried doing a `pod repo update IQKeyboardManager` and then `pod install`? Your `Podfile.lock` must have an older version locked that has no support for Swift 3. Looks like versions `'4.0.6'` and up have support for Swift 3

Comment: Thanks for this! Would you be able to give me a step by step of what I should do to update this?